# Print Byte Array in Serial monitor screen of Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I need to print mentioned below byte array on the serial monitor screen of Arduino IDE

```
char b[]= {'0x7E', '0x00', '0x1C','0x90', '0x00', '0x13', '0XA2', '0x00', '0x41', '0x58', '0x1C', '0xCB', '0xFF', '0xFE', '0xC1', '0x7C', '0x00','0x0F', '0x00', '0x01', '0x00', '0x00', '0x37', '0x46', '0x46', '0x46', '0x00', '0x00', '0x00', '0xE7' };
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(b[]);
delay(500);
}
```

But whenever I am trying a print, the error problem was there which was not resolved which is

```
C:\Users\Misha\Desktop\test\Test_2\Test_2.ino: In function 'void loop()':

Test_2:8:18: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token

 Serial.println(b[]);

                  ^

exit status 1
expected primary-expression before ']' token
```

Any suggestions on this will be great help.

Comment: what is `b[]`? array variable is simply `b`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the suggestion whenever I have used `Serial.println(b)` also but its printing only the LSB value, I am not able to print the MSB values.

Comment: of course. you can't print an array with `print` and invalid syntax will not help with it

Comment: What MSB values are you on about? You just have a list of 8 bit values. There is nothing "MSB" or "LSB" about them. I think you need to go back and rethink what it is you are doing and asking and get the two to match up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t print an array in that way.

If you want to print an array of hexadecimal value (with two digits), you have to use `sprintf` function and change declaration of `b` array.

```
uint8_t b[]= {0x7E, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x90, 0x00, 0x13, 0XA2, 0x00, 
              0x41, 0x58, 0x1C, 0xCB, 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xC1, 0x7C, 
              0x00, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x37, 0x46, 
              0x46, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xE7};
int i;

void printHex(uint8_t num) {
  char hexCar[2];

  sprintf(hexCar, "%02X", num);
  Serial.print(hexCar);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for(i=0; i<sizeof(b); i++){
    printHex(b[i]);
 }

 Serial.println();
 delay(500);
}
```

The output produced is:

> 7E001C900013A20041581CCBFFFEC17C000F0001000037464646000000E7
>   7E001C900013A20041581CCBFFFEC17C000F0001000037464646000000E7
>   7E001C900013A20041581CCBFFFEC17C000F0001000037464646000000E7

Comment: Similar in this case It only displays the LSB values but no MSB values were displayed in serial monitor screen

Comment: What do you want to print? ASCII character or the hex value? In serial monitor Do you want this: 7E 00 ... ?

Comment: @varuljain I updated the answer.

Comment: Btw the buffer is too small to contain two characters and '\0' character.

Comment: I am anxious to understand HOW to use the Serial Monitor

Comment: I am anxious to understand HOW to use the Serial Monitor input line to write/change the elements of the array (instead of declaring the array as is done in [1 Answer ] above. marty Jan 8 2020